# How to filter out a sequence of repeated value with repetitions greater than a specific number

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with a set of data.  The data is formatted in the following manner:

```
  SEQ       STEP
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 x         4.00
2 x         0   
3 x         0   
4 x         4.00
5 x         0   
6 x         0
```

I have used the following code to group the data by SEQ because there are approximately 50000 SEQ IDs:

```
steps%>%
group_by(SEQ)
```

I would now like to filter out the zeros "0" under PAXSTEP if they occur in sequence more than 60 time, i.e. if rows 5-100 had zeros and row 101 has a number > 0 under PAXSTEP I would like to filter out rows 5-100.

```
steps%>%
 group_by(SEQ)%>%
```

Comment: with `lag` you are just checking a single value, `n=60` rows back up in your tibble. if you want to check a full sequence of 60 values not changing, you need to do something more. One strategy would be to use something like cumulative sums on `PAXSTEP`, then you could indeed just check if a single value 60 rows down would remain the same (assuming you have no negative values in PAXSTEP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible approach. I created a sample data given your sample data wasn't enough to look into your case. I purposely created a sequence of 0 (60 times) in one group in `SEQN` and tried to remove it. For each `SEQN`, I created sub groups using `diff()` and `cumsum()`. Whenever there is absolute difference more than 0 in `PAXSTEP`, a new sub group is created. With my sample data, you will see sub group number 1 for the sequence of 0 in `SEQN` == 1 (row 2-61). I further used this variable for grouping. The final step was a logical check. You target `PAXSTEP == 0` and you want to remove sequences of 0 that is longer than 60, right? By using `n()`, you can count how many elements stay in each group (grouped by `SEQN` and `check`). If `PAXSTEP == 0` and `n() >= 60`, that means you want to remove the rows satisfying the condition. For subsetting reason, here I negated the conditions. The following code removes 60 rows from `SEQN` == 1 that contain 0 in `PAXSTEP`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(SEQN = rep(c(1,2), each = 100),
                   value = 1:200,
                   PAXSTEP = c(1, rep(0, times = 60), 62:200))

group_by(mydf, SEQN) %>%
mutate(check = cumsum(c(F, abs(diff(PAXSTEP)) > 0))) %>%
group_by(check, add = TRUE) %>%
filter(!(PAXSTEP == 0 & n() >= 60)) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-check)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was much easier then I thought.